# Is this a sufficient condition for a curve to be perpendicular to a fixed point?

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose we have a fixed point $p \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and a smooth curve $\beta \colon I \to \mathbb{R}^3$  such that $\beta(0)\perp p$ and $\beta'(t) \perp p $ for all $ t \in I$. Is this condition enough to ensure that $\beta(t) \perp p$ for all $t \in I$ ?
My work so far is treating the case in which all of the coordinate functions of $\beta$ are analytic. In this case we get that:
$$
\langle \beta(t),p\rangle = \sum_{k=0}^\infty  \frac{t^k}{k!}\langle \beta^{(k)}(0),p \rangle = 0 
$$
But i think that's asking a lot to $\beta$.
Any help in the general case would be appreciated.

*Note: Smooth curve means having derivatives of all orders.*

Comment: Differentiate the dot product $\langle \beta(t), p \rangle$.

Comment: You should write $p$ as a vector, say $v$, not as a point.